# GameTime class replacement for XNA-Control in Windows Forms environment

Tags: c#, winforms, time, xna

Hello I am currently trying to embed an XNA module in my project which is a Windows Forms Application, using this tutorial: 
http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/winforms_series_1.
I guess that's the best tutorial around for easy practice, so I decided to keep up with it.

The problem arises when I needed the GameTime, in their implementation of the XNA Control, the GameTime does not exist. I tried looking for a rapid solution in Google, and tried to find an explanation of how GameTime is implemented in a regular XNA Game, but the more information I found, I became more confused... 
Here are the questions:

- In a regular XNA Game, the GameTime.ElapsedGameTime, the description says "The amount of elapsed game time since last update." - What does that mean? Does it give the milliseconds that has passed? But that doesn't make any sense because there is a constant time span between the  drawings and updates, and it happens every 16ms more-or-less.. It seems pointless to me and I'd like a little explanation here. I know the ElapsedGameTime plays a big role in smoothing motions with Linear Interpolations, but it doesn't make any sense if its maximum value is around 16ms
- Is there any implementation of the exact GameTime in an XNA Control? If not then what is the best practice to simulate GameTime in Windows Forms?

Sorry if my questions have been asked before, it kinda really important to me right now and have already tried to get an answer based on Google search, but failed to get any clear ones

Comment: FYI: You can have variable time span by setting the `Game.IsFixedTimeStep` to false

Answer (score 1):

`GameTime` provides the fixed or variable time elapsed since the last update, total amount of time since the start of the game and a `IsRunningSlowly` flag related to target performance.

Here is a nice article about the game timers in WinForms: [When WinForms met Game Loop](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/12/06/when-winforms-met-game-loop.aspx)

Comment: +1. That article, like most of his, is really the best answer here.

Comment: Better than using the default Xna Game class with all the functionality? :P

Comment: I have assumed (maybe incorrectly though), that OP can't use the Game class for some reason, and that's why he needs to implement the game loop himself.

Answer (score 1):

Behind the scenes, Xna provides functionality to fix the time step to approx 60 FPS. Unless you write that functionality into a winforms application, you won't have it. But working with a variable time step instead of that fixed time step is a good option.

I've tackled this problem by using a Stopwatch in the class that derives from the GraphicsDeviveControl.

Then, in the Draw() method, set a variable to it's elapsed time, then reset it. Here is an example:

```
public class XnaControl : GraphicsDeviceControl
{
    Stopwatch timer;
```

later, in the draw method

```
    protected override void Draw()
    {
        float elapsed = (float)timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
        timer.Restart();
        systemBase.UpdateSimulation(elapsed);
        systemBase.DrawSimulation(elapsed);
    }
```

Now, by sending 'elapsed' along with the Update & draw, you can calculate things in an interpolation manner like any variable time step game/application.

Comment: Can you show an example of getting the mouse movement for XnaControl?

Answer (score 0):

The `GameTime` struct is more relevant if you choose to use a variable time step. By default XNA runs a fixed time step (so all updates occur at a regular interval in normal circumstances).

I'm guessing you need a `GameTime` because you want to refresh the control not only based on user input (i.e. like a game, where things happen even if the user doesn't touch anything).

In that case one simple approach would be to have a timer control on your form that simply called your update/render functions. You'd pass in the timer's interval to your functions. You could have your functions that in XNA would normally accept a `GameTime` just accept a double or float etc. or you can just create a `GameTime` yourself based on the interval.

Another option would be to create another thread that would try and update as fast as possible (maybe up to a point). This would then raise callbacks on the UI thread, that would do the updating/rendering. Dealing with the `GameTime` would be simiar to the above in that you can record when you last ran, and pass the difference between then and now as the time delta.

Answer (score 0):

[GameTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.gametime_members.aspx).[ElapsedGameTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.gametime.elapsedgametime.aspx) gives you a [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) object where you can then retrieve any unit of time you'd like, including (but not limited to) milliseconds through the [TotalMiliseconds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalmilliseconds.aspx) property.

The reason the TimeSpan is always the same is because XNA uses a fixed time step by default. You can change this by setting the [Game.IsFixedTimeStep](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.game.isfixedtimestep.aspx) property as Dmitry points out in the comments. There is an excellent discussion about timesteps in this question [Fixed time step vs Variable time step](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1589/fixed-time-step-vs-variable-time-step), as well as some code to implement them.

Answer (score 0):

This code works well and the only difference is the constructor inside the game class, the rest is like a normal xna game for windows.

This is the code I have used for this [editor for 2D sprites and skeletal animations](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4RhAGEUFNmQ)

**Program.cs**

```
namespace SpriteEditor
{
#if WINDOWS
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {               
            Application.EnableVisualStyles( );
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault( false );
            XnaControlGame.CreateAndShow<SkeletonManagerDialog, SkeletonXnaGame>( );           
        }
    }
#endif
```

**Form**

```
public partial class SkeletonManagerDialog : Form, IXnaFormContainer
{        
    public Control XnaControl { get { return spriteBoneEditor1.XnaPicture; } }
    public XnaControlGame Game { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

**XnaGame**

```
public partial class SkeletonXnaGame : XnaControlGame
{
    public SkeletonXnaGame( IntPtr ptr, Form form, Control control ) 
        : base( ptr, form, control ) { }

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    protected override void Update( GameTime gameTime )        
    {
        float Seconds = ( float ) gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

        HandleMouse( );

        if ( TryHandleCamera( ) ) return;
        if ( MouseIsInsideViewport) HandleLeftClick( Seconds );
        if ( SkeletonManager.SelectedBone != null ) UpdateSelectedBone( Seconds );
        if ( SkeletonManager.SelectedShape != null ) UpdateSelectedShape( Seconds );
        if ( SkeletonManager.CurrentSequence != null ) SkeletonManager.CurrentSequence.Update( Seconds );
        base.Update( gameTime );
    }

    ....
}
```

**XnaControlGame.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;

namespace SpriteEditor
{
    public interface IXnaFormContainer
    {
        Control XnaControl { get; }
        XnaControlGame Game { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class XnaControlGame : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {
        public Control Parent { get; private set; }

        public static void CreateAndShow<T, Q>( )
            where T : Form, IXnaFormContainer, new( )
            where Q : XnaControlGame
        {
            using ( T form = new T( ) )
            {
                form.Show( );

                using ( Q game = ( Q ) Activator.CreateInstance( typeof( Q ), new object[] { form.XnaControl.Handle, form, form.XnaControl } ) )
                {
                    form.Game = game;
                    game.Parent = form.XnaControl;
                    game.Run( );
                }
            }
        }


        #region Private Vars to Build Embedded Xna Control

        IntPtr _XnaDrawingSurface;
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;

        System.Windows.Forms.Form parentForm;
        System.Windows.Forms.Control controlXna;

        System.Windows.Forms.Control gameForm;

        #endregion

        #region Constructor

        public XnaControlGame( IntPtr handle,
            System.Windows.Forms.Form parentForm,
            System.Windows.Forms.Control surfaceControl )
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager( this );
            graphics.GraphicsProfile = GraphicsProfile.Reach;
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";

            this.parentForm = parentForm;
            this.controlXna = surfaceControl;

            gameForm = System.Windows.Forms.Control.FromHandle( this.Window.Handle );
            gameForm.VisibleChanged += new EventHandler( gameForm_VisibleChanged );
            controlXna.SizeChanged += new EventHandler( pictureBox_SizeChanged );

            // preparing device settings handler. 
            _XnaDrawingSurface = handle;
            Mouse.WindowHandle = handle;

            graphics.PreparingDeviceSettings += OnPreparingDeviceSettings;
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = (controlXna.Width > 0) ? controlXna.Width : 50;
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = (controlXna.Height > 0) ? controlXna.Height : 50;

            parentForm.FormClosed += delegate( object sender, System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventArgs e )
            {
                this.Exit( );
                Application.Exit( );
            };
        }

        #endregion

        #region Events

        private void OnPreparingDeviceSettings( object sender, PreparingDeviceSettingsEventArgs e )
        {
            e.GraphicsDeviceInformation.PresentationParameters.DeviceWindowHandle = _XnaDrawingSurface;
        }

        private void gameForm_VisibleChanged( object sender, EventArgs e )
        {
            if ( gameForm.Visible == true )
                gameForm.Visible = false;
        }

        void pictureBox_SizeChanged( object sender, EventArgs e )
        {
            if ( parentForm.WindowState !=
                System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Minimized )
            {
                graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = controlXna.Width;
                graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = controlXna.Height;
                graphics.ApplyChanges( );
                OnSizeChanged( );
            }
        }

        protected virtual void OnSizeChanged( ) { }

        #endregion         
    }      
}
```